# ngOptions: select fetched value OR select default value

Tags: angularjs, ng-options

After looking at the documentation and numerous questions here on SO, I can't find a solution for my issue. I have a dropdown that is populated with data from a database. To fill this, I use ngOptions with the `select as` method.

```
<select ng-model="modelthing" ng-options="item.id as item.description for item in categories">
```

Now what I want is a default option (which can be changed by an admin, so it can't be hardcoded as an `<option>`) if no value has been selected before, and the selected value when there is one of those.

```
$scope.categories = $http.get(thingurl)
    .then(function (result) {
        $scope.categories = result.data;
        //$scope.modelthing= $scope.categories[1].id; 
        $scope.modelthing= 1; 
    });
```

<s>There are two problems with this, first of all the `[1]` selects the second entry in the json data, not the one that has `1` as key. 
And second: [Solved this with help from Icycool in their comment below.](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/6564#issuecomment-51615589)</s>

When I keep opening and closing a populated form about half of the time I get the default value, and the other half I get the actual selected value. This is obviously because the `ng-model="modelthing"` gets overwritten when I fetch the data form the populated form and the code runs synchronous. Is there a way to make sure this runs asynchronous? Or is my approach just plain wrong?

---

*Other things I've tried so far:*

I noticed that when I used the `select as item in items` phrase in ngOptions, the options in my select have a `value="number:3"` instead of a plain number. [Using `track by` in ngOptions](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/6564#issuecomment-51615589) instead of `select as` fixed this, but had as unforseen affect that my selected values wouldn't match the ones in the dropdown, because those are plain `3` in stead of `number:3`.

A solution that *does* work, but feels very unAngular and a tad dirty, is to check on form initialization if the `modelthing` model is empty, and if so, set it to the default value.

Comment: update the post with your json  data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `id` is easier to manage than using the object itself.

```
<select ng-model="modelthing" 
        ng-options="item.id as item.description for item in categories">

$scope.categories = $http.get(thingurl)
    .then(function (result) {
        $scope.categories = result.data;
        $scope.modelthing = 1; // your model is bound to id not the object
    });
```

Note that `integer` `1` and `string` `"1"` might not be treated the same in this case, it needs to match the type returned in JSON.

---

Part 2: Do you mean the model and the selections comes from different `$http` calls? It can be fixed by checking for existing value before applying the default value

```
function getData() {
  $http.then(function(data) {
    $scope.selections = data;
    if (!$scope.selected) $scope.selected = data[0].id;
  })
}

function getSelected() {
  $http.then(function(data) {
    $scope.selected = data.id;
  })
}
```

By this way the final value after both async calls resolve will always be the retrieved id, regardless of the order.

The only small problem remaining is the default value will show for a moment until the real selected value returns. You may leave this behavior or hide the selections until the selected value returns.

Comment: Ah, yes, you're right, that is the proper way to declare the ng-model. Thanks! Though it doesn't solve the synchronous calls... this declaration and the one that grabs the entire model run side by side apparently, causing sometimes the default value to show, and sometimes the selected value. :(

Comment: That works! Is this an accepted "Angular way" of going at this?  And are you sure this makes the calls asynchronous? For example, if the `getData()` function unexpectedly finishes before the `getSelected()` has started, isn't the `$scope.selected` value still empty at that point? (I mean, I can't seem to break it. works flawlessly so far, this is just out of curiosity). Thanks!

Comment: @Kablam Actually `$http` is async by default. Your problem was 2 async calls returning in different sequence, but not the code sometimes running async and sometimes sync. If `selections` return before `selected`, Angular will show the default value first, and then update to the real value when it returns automatically, which is the problem I described in the last paragraph.

Comment: I see! Thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 0):

> - You need add a new object *(with negative value or 0)* to your **array** *(categories).*
> - assign the last object to your **model** *(modelthing)* object.

Kindly try this my below code (otherwise get it to a Key)

```
$scope.categories = $http.get(thingurl)
    .then(function (result) {
        $scope.categories = result.data;
        $scope.categories.Push(id:"0",description:"Select");
        $scope.modelthing = $scope.categories[$scope.categories.length - 1];
    });
```

**Update:**

> 1)There are two problems with this, first of all the [1] selects the second entry in the json data, not the one that has 1 as key

The array of index is starting With 0, not with 1. So if the key looks 1 but the index value is 0. **You are using *array* not *arraylist*** . Does make sense?

Just put 0 instead of 1 like

`$scope.categories[0].id`

> 2)When I keep opening and closing a populated form about half of the time I get the default value, and the other half I get the actual selected value. This is obviously because the ng-model="modelthing" gets overwritten when I fetch the data form the populated form and the code runs synchronous. Is there a way to make sure this runs asynchronous? Or is my approach just plain wrong?

Just declare your model object on globally with empty data

```
$scope.categories = [];
$scope.modelthing = {};
```

**Update 2**

> 3) I was trying to select a value based on its key, not its place in the array, because the keys are not necessarily placed in the array in ascending order

```
var key = 1; //it's not static 
for( var i=0;i<$scope.categories.length;i++)
{
  if($scope.categories[i].id==key)// Once your key is correct,then the value will be assign
  {
    $scope.modelthing = $scope.categories[i]
  }
}
```

Comment: This would work, for a default value that is "Select". What I want is to pre-select a value from the dataset that I fetch from the server, I want to set the dropdown to (for example) the value with key = 3.

Comment: Yeah, I see now, I get what you're trying to say. I know that an array starts with 0. I was trying to select a value based on its key, not its place in the array, because the keys are not necessarily placed in the array in ascending order.

Comment: I really appreciate your help, thank you for taking time to respond. But altough your **Update 2** solution does select the right value, it's essentially the same as @Icycool's solution, albeit a bit more complex. My current problem is as described in the starting post; the data is called synchonously, leading to problems diaplaying the correct value.